# Unable to make web request through proxy server

Tags: c#, .net, security, sharepoint, proxy

My sharepoint webpart is throwing an error when calling HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream when the request is made through a proxy server.  The error is "unable to connect to the remote server."  The client's machine (where this is failing) is set to use a specific proxy server (Use proxy server for your LAN) on IE settings.

Do I need to add any proxy setting in the config to get this to work?

Also, what's the easiest way to reproduce my client's scenario--how can I add a proxy on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set autodetect to false in web.config

```
   <system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
        <proxy autoDetect="false" />
      </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
```

Comment: Do I also need to set useDefaultCredentials to false?

Comment: I would try both. I think I usually set that value to true in code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Sharepoint log to get a detailed error description.

Usually this can be found here:
C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS\